# How to сreate a regular expression for the dollar currency?

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a regular expression for the dollar currency.
This examples should be find by regex:

```
$ 10 
10$
10 $
1000005 dollars
```

And this shouldn't be match:

```
dollars 33
```

I have already use this expressions:

```
r_dollar = r'(\$|\$usd|usd|dollar(s)?|bucks)'
number = '([1-9]([0-9])+)'
valuta_with_num = u'(({0})\s?{1})|({1}\s?({0}))'.format(number, r_dolar)
currency_tags = re.compile(u'({0})'.format(valuta_with_num))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want `dollars one million and five` to be captured or not?

Comment: @Asunez, I want 'dollars one million and five' not to be captured.

Comment: @DmitrySidenko But [your regex does not match it already](https://regex101.com/r/kK6VVk/1). What is the problem then? Did you use `re.findall` with your regex and got weird results?

Comment: I want to create short regex sentence which got $ 33 and 33 $  and 33 dollars, and not to match dollars 33. Using in example of `dollars one million and five` was my fault. It wiil be in next task and it doesn't link with current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using your alternation could be:

```
(?:\$\s*\d+|\d+\s*(?:\$?usd|\$|dollars?|bucks))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\$\s*\d+` Match a dollar sign, 0+ times a whitespace char and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+\s*` Match 1+ digits followed by 0+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:`Non capturing group

    - `\$?usd|\$|dollars?|bucks` Match any of the options where `\$?` is an optional dollar sign
  - `)`  Close non capturing group
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dVRTo4/1)

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird for answer. It passes all my test

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this, is by creating multiple alternatives:

`(\$\s*\d+|\d+\s*\$|\d+\s+dollars|1 dollar)`

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/sAiDOo/2

It is the trivial approach, but it works nicely. The wrapping parentheses may not be necessary depending on your use case.

**Explanation:**

We have 4 separate options available, all separated by the `|` (pipe).

1. `\$\s*\d+`: Search for a dollar sign (remember to escape it!), followed by any number of spaces (`*`: 0 or more), followed by at least one digit (`+`: 1 or more)
2. `\d+\s*\$`: Same thing, just the other way around: Search for at least one digit, followed by any number of spaces, followed by a dollar sign.
3. `\d+\s+dollars`: Search for at least one digits, followed by at least one space, followed by the word dollars.
4. `1 dollar`: Search for the exact string `1 dollar`, since it will not be matched by `dollars` (plural s).

Answer (score 1):

You may  use

```
import re
strs = ['Some $ 10 here', 
        'And 10$ here',
        'And 10 $  here',
        'And 1000005 dollars here',
        'And dollars one million and five here']
r_dollar = r'(?:\$(?:usd)?|(?:dollar|buck)s?)' # USD dollar name
r_textnumber = r'\b(?!\s)(?:[\sa-]|zero|one|tw(?:elve|enty|o)|th(?:irt(?:een|y)|ree)|fi(?:ft(?:een|y)|ve)|(?:four|six|seven|nine)(?:teen|ty)?|eight(?:een|y)?|ten|eleven|forty|hundred|thousand|[mb]illion|and)+\b(?<!\s)'
r_number = r'(?:[1-9][0-9]+|{})'.format(r_textnumber) # Dollar amount
valuta_with_num = r'{0}\s?{1}|{1}\s?{0}'.format(r_number, r_dollar) # Main regex
print(valuta_with_num)
currency_tags = re.compile(valuta_with_num)

for s in strs:
    print(currency_tags.findall(s))
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/eFpdXQ). Output:

```
['$ 10']
['10$']
['10 $']
['1000005 dollars']
['dollars one million and five']
```

The regex part to match numbers as words is

```
\b(?!\s)(?:[\sa-]|zero|one|tw(?:elve|enty|o)|th(irt(een|y)|ree)|fi(?:ft(?:een|y)|ve)|(?:four|six|seven|nine)(?:teen|ty)?|eight(?:een|y)?|ten|eleven|forty|hundred|thousand|[mb]illion|and)+\b(?<!\s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0L5IQ3/2). Details:

- `\b(?!\s)` - a word boundary not followed with whitespace
- `(?:\s|[a-]|zero|one|tw(?:elve|enty|o)|th(irt(een|y)|ree)|fi(?:ft(?:een|y)|ve)|(?:four|six|seven|nine)(?:teen|ty)?|eight(?:een|y)?|ten|eleven|forty|hundred|thousand|[mb]illion|and)+` - 1 or more repetitions of a whitespace, `a`, `-`, `zero`, ..., `nine`, `ten`, `eleven`, `twelve`..., `twenty`, `hundred`, `thousand`, `million` and `billion`
- `\b(?<!\s)` - a word boundary not preceded with whitespace.

Comment: As per OPs question, `dollars one million and five` should not be a part of the output. Or at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: @Asunez I undestood it that OP wants to also extract such matches, but the current regex does not do that.

Comment: I asked in the comment of the question for clarification, this is obviously not clear question.

Comment: @Asunez I have checked OP solution, it [matches](https://regex101.com/r/kK6VVk/1) the first test set, but does not match the last case. So, I think my answer is just what is required.

Comment: Seems like it, then other answers are not valid as they do not try to match the last case.

Comment: Wiktor, please check last comment from OP on the question - he states that the line `dollar one million(...)` should not be captured

Comment: @Asunez OP made a mistake when posted the input that should not be matched. [This](https://regex101.com/r/kK6VVk/2) is the real test and the string not to be matched is `dollars 33`, and [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/77pqgg/1) will match it. Hopefully, it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @christoph 
but it can be shortened by thinking other way round

```
^(\$|\d+)(\s*)(\d+|dollar|dollars|\$)$
```

See it in action - https://regex101.com/r/IWnHni/1

**Explanation**

1. First group(bracket) tells us what can come in first place i.e $ or digit
2. Second group is for space
3. Third group tell us what can come after space i.e $ or dollar or dollars or digit

Hope this helps

Comment: You can shorten it even more if you make the `s` in `dollars` optional :) Check this: https://regex101.com/r/IWnHni/2

Comment: Yes I second you 

Comment: This won't work correctly, as it will also match `123 123`.